# Failed to change log level of slf4j simplelogger

Tags: logging, slf4j

jdk 6, slf4j 1.7.5

Layout bleow:

```
.
├── com
│   └── to
│       └── Main.class
├── simplelogger.properties
├── slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar
└── slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar
```

Main.java below:

```
package com.to;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class Main {

    final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Main.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        logger.info("error {}", logger.isErrorEnabled());
        logger.info("info {}", logger.isInfoEnabled());
        logger.info("debug {}", logger.isDebugEnabled());
    }

}
```

simplelogger.properties is changed below:

```
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLog=error
```

Run the test, the output shows that the default log level isn't changed at all.

```
$ java -cp .:slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar:slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar com.to.Main

[main] INFO com.to.Main - error true
[main] INFO com.to.Main - info true
[main] INFO com.to.Main - debug false
```

The same problem happens even if the system property is changed below,

```
Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLog=error
```

**@EDIT**

According the [reference](http://slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/impl/SimpleLogger.html), the correct property name should be org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLog`Level`, i had just commented out the line from the [template](https://github.com/qos-ch/slf4j/blob/master/slf4j-simple/src/test/resources/simplelogger.properties) that has the wrong property name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It could be, that the propertyname ist wrong:
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLog => org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel

source:
http://www.slf4j.org/api/index.html?org/slf4j/impl/SimpleLogger.html